# Two of the six buttons I created in Telegram bot don't work, why?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import telebot
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('6427511998:AAGO3q9JS06PLkxQblJFVQ-RNJwEpNBYZ_M')
curency = CurrencyConverter()
amount = 0
buttons = ''

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    global buttons
    buttons = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('100')
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('200')
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('500')
    buttons.row(btn1, btn2, btn3)
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('1000')
    btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('2000')
    btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('5000')
    buttons.row(btn4, btn5, btn6)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здарова, напиши сумму', reply_markup=buttons)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, summ)
    
def summ(message):
    global amount
    global buttons
    try:
        amount = int(message.text.strip())
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка. Введите сумму(числовой формат)', reply_markup=buttons)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, summ)
        return
    
    if amount > 0:
        buttons2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USD/RUB', callback_data='USD/RUB')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USD/EUR', callback_data='USD/EUR')
        btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('EUR/RUB', callback_data='EUR/RUB')
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('RUB/USD', callback_data='RUB/USD')
        btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('EUR/USD', callback_data='EUR/USD')
        btn6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('RUB/EUR', callback_data='RUB/EUR')
        btn7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('OTHER', callback_data='OTHER')
        buttons2.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите валютную пару', reply_markup=buttons2)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка. Число должно быть больше нуля', reply_markup=buttons)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, summ)
    
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_data(callback_data):
    callback_data_values = callback_data.data.upper().split('/')
    res = curency.convert(amount, callback_data_values[0], callback_data_values[1])
    bot.send_message(callback_data.message.chat.id, f'Результат: {res}. Можете снова вписать сумму и валютную парую')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(callback_data.message, summ)
    
    
bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

There are 7 buttons created in the `summ` function, `btn1` to `btn7`. `btn7` has not been configured yet. The callback_data function converts callback values from buttons. `btn1` and `btn3` cause the bot to crash. I can't find my error.

I'm working in VSCode.

I tried to create a separate script to handle these two buttons but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

What error do you see in terminal?

If you don't see anything in terminal, try to change your code:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_data(callback_data):
    callback_data_values = callback_data.data.upper().split('/')
    try:
       res = curency.convert(amount, callback_data_values[0], callback_data_values[1])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        bot.send_message(callback_data.message.chat.id, f'Результат: {res}. Можете снова вписать сумму и валютную парую')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(callback_data.message, summ)
```

And be careful with posting your Bot Token.

Comment: I'm not worried about the token, it's a test bot. but about the error, I changed the code a bit, and the terminal said `RateNotFoundError(currency_converter.currency_converter.RateNotFoundError: 2023-10-13 not in RUB bounds 2005-04-01/2022-03-01)`
I also did some debugging of the code, but it didn't have any mistakes.

Comment: As it's said in the documentation of this library,
`Note that the currency converter does not query the API in real time, to avoid the overhead of the HTTP request. It uses embedded data in the library, which might not be up to date. If you need the latest data, please refer to the data section.`
So it looks like there is no data for this currency on these dates in the library's database.
Try updating the library. Or use data from your data file as it's described in the documentation.